# python pandas dataframe how to apply a function to each time period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe`,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(9), 'col2': list(range(7)) + [np.nan] *2}, 
    index = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=9, freq='0.5S'))
df
Out[109]: 
                         col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000     0   0.0
2000-01-01 00:00:00.500     1   1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:01.000     2   2.0
2000-01-01 00:00:01.500     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:00:02.000     4   4.0
2000-01-01 00:00:02.500     5   5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:03.000     6   6.0
2000-01-01 00:00:03.500     7   NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:04.000     8   NaN
```

As can been seen above, each second there are two data point. What I would like to do is for the two rows in a second, if both cols in the latest row has valid number, that row will be chosen; if either cols in the latest row is invalid, we will see previous row is valid for bot col, if valid, we will chose previous row, otherwise we will skip the second. The resuling dataframe looks like this,

```
                         col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00.000     1   1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:01.000     3   3.0
2000-01-01 00:00:02.000     5   5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:03.000     6   6.0
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `reindex` after dropna we reindex , then both of the columns become `NaN`, In this situation if we using `last` , we will not select any item from this row (correlated with your previous question )

```
df.dropna().reindex(df.index).resample('1s').last().dropna()
Out[175]: 
                     col1  col2
2000-01-01 00:00:00   1.0   1.0
2000-01-01 00:00:01   3.0   3.0
2000-01-01 00:00:02   5.0   5.0
2000-01-01 00:00:03   6.0   6.0
```